# Unity 3D Camera dot projectionMatrix

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, camera

To be brief,

I would like to achieve the same camera view of a MOBA like game, If you ever noticed for example in league of legends or Dota 2, the camera is not in a perspective mode nor in a 100% orthographic.

(eventhough it's more close to an orthographic one than to a perspective one)

for example if you start moving the camera to left or right from point A to B you can see some faces of some unmoving objects (like turrets) you couldn't see from point A, but it still keeps the dimension and the size of the objects the same,

unlike an orthographic camera you can't see another face of the unmoving (or moving) object no matter how many times you try to move the camera.

I hope I was clear, I know it must be in the matrix projection I have been told that I need an "off axis projection", which I have no idea what it is, OpenGL and rendering things are not my strongest spot.

any help will be much appreciated.

here is the script I'm using with some tweaks still getting nothing :

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-projectionMatrix.html

Edit :

For the script : I'm using the script I linked earlier I didn't come up with anything new here that's why I'm here.

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float left = -0.2F;
    public float right = 0.2F;
    public float top = 0.2F;
    public float bottom = -0.2F;
    void LateUpdate() {
        Camera cam = camera;
        Matrix4x4 m = PerspectiveOffCenter(left, right, bottom, top, cam.nearClipPlane, cam.farClipPlane);
        cam.projectionMatrix = m;
    }
    static Matrix4x4 PerspectiveOffCenter(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far) {
        float x = 2.0F * near / (right - left);
        float y = 2.0F * near / (top - bottom);
        float a = (right + left) / (right - left);
        float b = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        float c = -(far + near) / (far - near);
        float d = -(2.0F * far * near) / (far - near);
        float e = -1.0F;
        Matrix4x4 m = new Matrix4x4();
        m[0, 0] = x;
        m[0, 1] = 0;
        m[0, 2] = a;
        m[0, 3] = 0;
        m[1, 0] = 0;
        m[1, 1] = y;
        m[1, 2] = b;
        m[1, 3] = 0;
        m[2, 0] = 0;
        m[2, 1] = 0;
        m[2, 2] = c;
        m[2, 3] = d;
        m[3, 0] = 0;
        m[3, 1] = 0;
        m[3, 2] = e;
        m[3, 3] = 0;
        return m;
    }
}
```

For the screens : Focus your eyes on the turrets of course, here is the Screens, since I don't have much reputation I can't post pictures or more than two links, so
here is a dropbox link containing only pictures (4).

2 of unity3d environement, 
and 2 of League Of Legends Camera,

observe the Turret in the LoL's Screenshots, and the Pillars in Unity3d with an isometric camera, You can tell that these are using the same matrix, if I move the camera to the right I can see the face of the turret that I could not see from my previous standing point, and that's the effect I'm looking to achieve.

Assuming that everyone agrees that League of Legends is using an isometric camera or at least something close to it.

Thanks for your time.

[Pictures in dropbox link is here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pd0ub1k5h4tg20e/AADh_O7vwi2xSJ_8wbGQv5Ova?dl=0)

Comment: Please post some screens with examples of the camera view.

Comment: Besides the screenshots, also include a actual sample of the code in question, instead of a link only.

Comment: Im aware of your response, I'll post some examples as soon as possible with more details.